# Increasing Address Lines

Tags: eeprom

I have stumbled into a problem where I need more address lines in my eeprom, my eeprom only has 15 address lines and I need atleast 28 address line for my project. What would you suggest I do? I need a larger eeprom for my graphics card project, it's 1024 x 768 and I wanted to use an eeprom to just display an image in that res. When I was designing this I had realized very late into the project that 15 address lines was not enough. I'm not sure if I should just get a completely different type of memory or to stay with eeprom.

Comment: Get a much larger EEPROM, and/or use several EEPROMs.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What exactly are you doing with this EEPROM?

Comment: What's producing the 28 address lines? How is it using them? Why don't you talk ***a lot more*** about what you are on about here? You are leaving us completely in the dark.

Comment: do you have any understanding of the cost of the eeprom of that size?

Comment: You would need 8192 of those EEPROMs, with a bunch of extra logic to decode the extra address lines into chip select lines.  It looks like you need to re-think what sort of ROM you're using.

Comment: When you write that you "need at least 28 address line for my project", do you mean that your EEPROM needs to respond at an address which requires 28 bits to encode - for example an address somewhere in the 0x08000000 range or higher? Would it be safe to assume that your EEPROM doesn't need to fill the entire address range all the way down to 0x00000000?

Comment: How much address space do you actually need? Just because you have 28 data lines doesn't mean you need to use all of them. You could also use 2 EEPROMS, one you wire to the low word and the other to the high word...

Comment: A 1024x768 image in 24 bit is 2.25 MiB in size, so that's the EEPROM size you need. A 28 bit byte-addressed chip would be 256 MiB and seems ridiculously oversized.

Comment: Please explain why you think you need 28 address lines (corresponding to a 256MB EEPROM). Maybe then we can expain why you don't.

Answer (score 1):

28 address lines is 256MB, big for an EEPROM. You will be hard pressed to find a parallel address type that big, as most systems have moved on to using serial addressing.

Maybe consider flash instead, and use a microcontroller to read it and load data to the graphics memory as needed. The microcontroller could also enable the use of compressed images.

Or, if your intention is to display static images, consider a digital signage solution instead?